# How to append text to a file at client's machine in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

I have an app in Blazor Webassembly (.NET 6) and I want to write (specifically **append**) any exceptions thrown to a file at client's pc. I don't want to involve backend for this.

I have tried some C# methods (such as WriteAsync of StreamWriter and WriteAllText of File) without any luck.

I was wondering if it is even possible to do something like that because the app is running in a browser. Is there a javascript method that achieve my goal? Or any way?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The browser is going to sandbox everything, you can't access files on the client machine

Comment: You can write a Text Blob to Local storage , write to IndexedDb or ask the user for permission to use a File: https://github.com/KristofferStrube/Blazor.FileSystemAccess

Comment: You can not access the client files by browser security. you have to send the error to the server to log it on the file or database. Create a special endpoint to post the client error message.